# Are rems replacing ems in CSS?

Tags: css

I was reading about [`rem` units in CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem-unit), and was a little confused. If you use `rem`, do you still use `em` or does that replace it?

For example:

```
.selector {
    margin-bottom:24px;
    margin-bottom:2.4rem;
    font-size:16px;
    font-size:1.6rem;
}
```

or

```
.selector {
    margin-bottom:24px;
    margin-bottom:2.4em;
    margin-bottom:2.4rem;
}
```

Just trying to figure out if `rem` takes the place of `em`, or if it's just another unit.

Comment: Include links for the greater good :)

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem covers the differences between rem and em.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rem is the em size for the root (html) element. That means once you define the html element's font-size, you can define all rem units relative to that.

For example:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
body { font-size: 1.4rem; } /* =14px */
h1   { font-size: 2.4rem; } /* =24px */
```

Rem is supported in Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 3.6+, and even Internet Explorer, but for [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/rem) you still have to use em, percent or px.

Comment: The main difference is that `rem` allows you to set `font-size` relative to the *root font size* (as above) of the `html` element, **not** relative to the *font-size of a parent element*. IE support? >= 9.

Comment: If you're going to lift code from the web, it's polite to provide the source: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem Or was it Snook who took it from here??

Comment: Use both px and rem. like in the above code set font-size: 14px; font-size 1.4rem. rem will work for modern browsers and px works for browsers in which rem is not supported. (source: snook.ca)

Answer (score 13):

No, it’s a different unit. `em` is based on the font-size of the parent, while `rem` is based on the root font-size, which I believe is the font-size of the `html` element.

Comment: So, is both of the example I had up correct? How would you properly use REM?

Comment: Either could be correct depending on your intent. The thing is `2.4em` is not necessarily the same as `2.4rem`, they get their base valuee form different elements, so if those elements have different font-sizes then your margin will be different.

Answer (score 3):

Rem is just one more unit, it doesn't replace em like em didn't replace pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Oldish topic, but I think it needs some more clarity.

Both `em` and `rem` are relative units, but `rem` is *always* relative to the `html` font size (the “root” element) rather than the inherited font size.

*Never* use `px`, or `pt` for that matter, on the screen. By hard coding the font size, you ignore the user’s personal preferred font settings and make zooming less cooperative.

Both `em` and `rem` have a useful role to play. Neither is perfect for all occasions. Here are some examples:

Use `rem` to avoid compounding sizing:

```
ul#something li { font-size: 1.2rem; }
    … or …
ul#something li { font-size: 1.2rem; }
```

The first one will result in nested lists having progressively *larger* sizes, since the `em` unit will inherit from a parent `li` element.

Use `rem` to set sizes *independently*:

```
article { font-size: .8rem; }       /* article base font size */
article>h2 { font-size: 2rem; }     /* … except for h2 */
```

And, of course you can use both:

```
div#something { font-size: 1.2rem; }        /*  based on html size */
div#something>h2 { font-size: 2em; }        /*  based on div#something */
```

Two years down the track, now, and we can use it, safely ignoring Legacy Browsers.